# Install repository and sync project error in android studio says all packages not available

Tags: android, android-studio, repository

I ran syn gradle for my android studio project but the error shows up that 
failed to resolve : com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0
when i click on install repository it says that all packages not available. Please help.

Comment: can you add more information, as your gradle...

Comment: I know the is a pretty late response, but you may want to check the details of the repository you downloaded, the one you downloaded may be obsolete or you just have the it as 23.1.0 instead of 23.0.1.

Answer (score 3):

Friend, the very best solution for most problems in android studio is to do a Invalidate caches/Restart.
Go to **File>Invalidate Cache/Restart** you will be shown a window asking to confirm restart.Be aware that local history will be cleared.

I got this problem several times and messed up with the studio.I googled for a solution and found this solution.If it doesnt help try update android support repository and other sdk components.